# Как запретить добавлять больше одной строки в баз DJANGO admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Как мне запретить в панели Django Admin добавлять больше одной строчки информации

Если он добавил одну то он еще может добавить только если удалит предыдущую

`models.py`

```
class Attempts(models.Model):
    count = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Число строчек на выдачу!')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.count
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Число'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Число выдач'
```

Comment: Переопределить метод [has_add_permission](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_add_permission), добавив в него нужные вам проверки?